# Clustering Algorithms for Complex Survey Studies

Tags: r, python

Which clustering algorithms can be used in complex survey designs? Can the kmeans algorithm be used?

I searched for literature using complex survey design data like NHANES, but they do not provide details of the specific algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a bit on what you're trying to do.  In one sense, clustering isn't affected by complex sampling: the distance between two points in the sample is the same no matter how they were sampled, so the clustering is the same.

If you want your clusters to estimate *population* clusters in some way then you might need to use weights.  For example, in $k$-means clustering by the usual iterative algorithm, computing the distances from centroids to points is not affected by clustering, but computing the centroids might be better done using a weighted mean if you want them to estimate the centroids of population clusters.  Similarly, in hierarchical clustering, when you're trying to find a merger of clusters than reduces (eg squared distance) loss by as much as possible it might be better to use a weighted loss.

I don't know of any specific research on this topic, though. It will be hard to find papers on cluster analysis under complex sampling because of keyword clash: "cluster" meaning primary sampling unit vs "cluster" meaning cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to do latent class analysis with clustering algorithm, to uncover hidden clusters. I don't know if I need to take weights into account. Like you said, retrieving content on related topics is difficult.